# Rotate instances already on normals

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have this deformed plane covered in some models I made:
[image: Deformed plane covered in models I made.]

While the models are rotated to match the normal of the surface, The only issue is that I want the models to face different directions, while the base of the model is still aligned with the normal of the surface.

My current geometry node layout:

[image: The Geometry node layout.]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Output of the node distribution of points on surface already contains finished rotation that you need.
[image]

Or you can get rotation from normals yourself:

[image]

Result:

[image]